# Trying to render an JSON dict received from elastic-search but getting [object Promise] error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, react-table

I am new to reactjs and javascript.

I am using the [elasticsearch npm package to interact with ElasticSearch (ES) API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/introduction.html)

I'm trying to iterate over JSON dicts I'm getting from the ES API, but am getting a consistent error as follows:

*"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.     in MoClassFetch (at src/index.js:10)"*

Appreciate any help coming my way.

**data**

```
      "hits" : {
        "total" : {
          "value" : 3,
          "relation" : "eq"
        },
        "max_score" : 9.174298,
        "hits" : [
          {
            "_index" : "obj-model",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "53183",
            "_score" : 9.174298,
            "_source" : {
              "MoClass" : {
                "Name" : "fvBD",
                "Description" : "A bridge domain is a unique ...",
                ...
            }
          ]
```

Updated the code based on Jacob's comments
**UPDATED MoClassFetch component**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    import elasticsearch from "elasticsearch";
    import ReactTable from 'react-table';
    import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';



    let client = new elasticsearch.Client({
      host: "10.48.37.181:9200",
      //log: "trace"
    });

    function ParseMoClassDict(moClassDict) {
        const moClassObject = Object.keys(moClassDict).map(key =>
            <moClass key={key} value={key}>{moClassDict[key]}</moClass>
            )


        return (
            <div>{moClassObject}</div>
        )
    }

        //const results = [];

    function MoClassFetch() {
      const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        client
          .search({
            index: 'aci-apic-obj-model_*',
            allow_partial_search_results: true,
            expand_wildcards: 'all',
            track_total_hits: true,
            q: 'MoClass.Name: fvBD',
            pretty: true
          })
          .then(({ body }) => setResults(body.hits.hits))      
      }, []);



        return (
            //console.log(results),
            <div className="search_results">
            <hr />
            <ul>
                return (
                    <li>
                        { results.map(result => {
                            return (
                                <li key={result._index}>
                                    {result._index}
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <ParseMoClassDict moClassDict={result._source.MoClass} />
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            );
                        })}
                    </li>
                );
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
    }



    export default MoClassFetch;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `MoClassFetch` as an `async function`. Async functions always return Promises, so you cannot use an async function as a component.

You have some async code you need to execute, however. This usually requires two things: some state so you can re-render once the async part completes, and an *effect* that performs the async operation. The [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hooks are the best way to do that with Function-based components.

Here's what this can look like:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MoClassFetch() {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    client
      .search({
        index: 'aci-apic-obj-model_*',
        allow_partial_search_results: true,
        expand_wildcards: 'all',
        track_total_hits: true,
        q: 'MoClass.Name: fvBD',
        pretty: true
      })
      .then(({ body }) => setResults(body.hits.hits))      
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="search_results">
      <hr />
      <ul>
        { 
          results.map(result => (
            <li key={result._index}>
              {result._index}
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <ParseMoClassDict moClassDict={result._source.MoClass} />
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          );
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jacob.  
I have adjusted my code based on your answer but now get the following error:
"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'hits' of undefined"

Comment: I tried to mimic the data you were consuming in your original code. I don't know what the structure of the body looks like; you'll have to analyze what comes back and adjust what gets passed into `setResults` (set a breakpoint there, look at the developer tools network tab, console.log, etc)

Comment: Thank you for the help @Jacob. the elasticsearch client allows for logging in console on anything going across the client connection and I see the API request returns the expected data. I'll post a subset of the data in a bit. I've also managed to get the needed data using a class and passing the data as props and then using bind and setState functions on 'this'.

Comment: added data in the original post

Comment: So you figured everything out? I can't help you with what to specifically select from the data because I don't know what data you need. If you're stuck on figuring out how to select your data from the JSON, that's probably a separate question topic.

Comment: I wouldn't say I figured everything out as I can only make it work when using a class and passing props and then setting state. The example I posted here is with using a separate component file without a class ... and there I cannot make it work ... even using your method ... the issue lies with the "body" var not being populated with the API request's JSON response ...